# Method is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d and C#, and I have two scripts:

**script 1:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }
     void Attack() {
        EnemyHealth eh = (EnemyHealth)target.GetComponent("EnemyHealth");
        eh.HealthRulse(-10);
    }

}
```

**script 2:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {
public int curHealth = 100;
public int maxHealth = 100;
public float healthBarLeangth;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    healthBarLeangth = Screen.width / 2;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
         HealthRulse(0);
    }
    void OnGUI() {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10,40,Screen.width / 2 / (maxHealth / curHealth),20),curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
    }
    void HealthRulse(int adj){
        if ( curHealth < 0)
            curHealth = 0;
        if (curHealth > maxHealth)
            curHealth = maxHealth;
        if(maxHealth < 1)
            maxHealth = 1;

        curHealth += adj;
        healthBarLeangth = (Screen.width / 2) * (curHealth / (float)maxHealth);
    }
}
```

The function "HeathRulse()" defined in "script 2" and called in "script 1" by GetComponent is throwing an error-
"Method is inaccessible due to its protection level"

I need help with that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level) or any of a hundred other similar questions...

Answer (score 5):

Since you're not defining any access modifier, method `HealthRulse` is private so you can't access it from outside `EnemyHealth` class

> The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default. Private nested types are not accessible from outside the containing type

Change the definition to

```
public void HealthRulse(int adj)
```