# Issue in reading DateTime field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, gridview

I have a text box that shows date of the system

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBoxdate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

        }
    }
```

and gets inserted into the Date type field of my database!
Now I am trying To create a view of my table on Grid view. In my WorkDataAccesslayer class I am retrieving values of my table. But getting error on retrieving Date i.e "WorkAssign.Date is inaccessible due to its protection level"

My WorkAssign class is as follows:

```
 public class Workassign
{ 

    public string listItem_1{get; set;} 
    public string listItem_2{get ; set;} 
    public string Description {get ; set;} 
    DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

and my WorkDataAccessLayer class is as follows:

```
public class WorkDataAccessLayer
{

    public static List<Workassign> GetTable()
    {
        List<Workassign> listValues = new List<Workassign>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Assign_Work", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Workassign ob = new Workassign();
                ob.listItem_1 =rdr["listitem_1"].ToString() ;
                ob.listItem_2 = rdr["listitem_2"].ToString();
                ob.Description = rdr["Description"].ToString();
                ob.Date = rdr["Date"].ToString();
                ob.Image = rdr["Image"].ToString();


                listValues.Add(ob);

            }


            return listValues;



        }


    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `Date` Property as public inline with the other properties :

`public DateTime Date {get; set;}`

You may prefer to modify the `get;` and `set;` to be private individually.

More info on C# Class Properties : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: thanks also When I am trying to retrieve Date value I am getting error on conversions.What appropriate conversions do i need to apply? I have tried this: 

ob.Date = rdr["Date"].ToShortDateString();

Comment: Try `DateTime.Parse(rdr["Date"].ToString());` or also look at the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method if you need to handle any invalid dates.

Answer (score 2):

Make it also `public`

```
public class Workassign
{ 

    public string listItem_1{get; set;} 
    public string listItem_2{get ; set;} 
    public string Description {get ; set;} 
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}  // default is internal
    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

otherwise you get the mentioned error at:

```
Workassign ob = new Workassign();
// ...
ob.Date = rdr["Date"].ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx