# c# protection access/visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
newdata.label1.Text = "Average Speed: " + AverageSpeed1.ToString("0.0");
        newdata.label2.Text = "Max Speed: " + MaxSpeed1.ToString("0.0");
        newdata.label3.Text = "Min Speed: " + MinSpeed1.ToString("0.0");
```

I'm trying to link the labels 1, 2, 3 between forms however when i try and link them through "newdata" it comes up with an error that says
Error   CS0122  'Form2.label1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error and link to my labels that are on the other form.

Thankyou for any help

Comment: Well, what access modifier did you use? And why did you tag this with Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Comment: And what about if you write in google "is inaccessible due to its protection level" and click on the first link which has the explanation and solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add public methods to your form to control its fields without much trouble.

```
public void SetAverageSpeed(double value)
{
    this.label1.Text = "Average Speed: " + AverageSpeed1.ToString("0.0");
}
```

And then you can do this

```
newdata.SetAverageSpeed(AverageSpeed1);
```

Note that method is public, your fields should remain private since they are auto generated by designer and by convention it isn't good to modify fields directly.

Answer (score -1):

What is newdata?, i think its a winform.

You need to change protection level of labels, seems its private. (change to public or internal)

If newdata is winform then change label property 'Modifier'.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you should be using an outside object to hold data that can appear on more than 1 form.  Then have your forms pull that data themselves when the form loads/updates.

```
public static class Speed
{
     public static float AverageSpeed;
     public static float MaxSpeed;
     public static float MinSpeed;
}

Form1_Load()
{
     label1.Text = Speed.AverageSpeed.ToString('0.0');
}

Form2_Load()
{
     label2.Text = Speed.MaxSpeed.ToString('0.0');
}
```