# struct inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, struct

I have declared a private struct inside a class.

When I try to use it, the compiler raises the error

```
struct inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This is the C# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class HUDanimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private struct udtThis
    {
        Color col1;
        Color col2;
        float wait;
        float fade;
    }

    private udtThis[] m = new udtThis[2];

    void Start()
    {
        udtThis n; //raises the compiler error
        n.wait = 0f;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @Fabjan it's a compiler error  'HUDanimator.udtThis.wait' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your compiler complains at the `n.wait = 0f;` line, because the struct's fields are private. Make them public:

```
private struct udtThis
{
    public Color col1;
    public Color col2;
    public float wait;
    float fade;
}
```

Then your code sample compiles just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the properties in the struct `public` or `internal` and access them the normal way.

I recommend encapsulating them like this:

```
    public Color Col1 { get; set; }
    public Color Col2 { get; set; }
    public float Wait { get; set; }
    public float Fade { get; set; }
```