# Unity Player Holdingball Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a basketball game in unity where a player from the 1st person is able to shoot the ball into the basket and I'm getting the error

> Assets/Project/Scripts/GameController.cs(19,14): error CS0122:
>   `Player.holdingBall' is inaccessible due to its protection level

how do I fix such an error?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Player player;
    public float resetTimer = 5f;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (player.holdingBall == false) {
            resetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (resetTimer <= 0) {
             SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is my player script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject ball;
    public GameObject playerCamera;

    public float ballDistance = 2f;
    public float ballThrowingForce = 5f;

    private bool holdingBall = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (holdingBall) {
      ball.transform.position = playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward * ballDistance;
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                holdingBall = false;
                ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
                ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(playerCamera.transform.forward * ballThrowingForce);
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool holdingBall = true;
```

is `private` and therefore can not be accessed using

```
player.holdingBall
```

---

either make it a `public` field like

```
public bool holdingBall = true;
```

the disadvantage of this solution is that than you would also be able to **set** the value elsewhere.

So better create a readonly `public` property for it like

```
private bool holdingBall = true;

public bool HoldingBall
{
    get { return holdingBall; }
}
```

so it can only be read but not set using

```
if(!player.HoldingBall) 
{
    ...
}
```

you could than also skip the private field completely and use only a property like

```
public bool HoldingBall{ get; private set; }
```

Comment: I put public bool HoldingBall
{
    get { return holdingBall; }
} in the top or bottom of my player script but it does not work. Where exactly in my script do I put this property?

Comment: what exactly means "does not work"? put it somewhere inside of the `Player` class

Comment: I have my class like this `code`public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

 public bool HoldingBall
 {
   get { return holdingBall; }
 }


 public GameObject ball;
 public GameObject playerCamera;

 public float ballDistance = 2f;
 public float ballThrowingForce = 5f;`code` and I get 2 unity errors. Am I putting it in the right place?

Comment: if using the `HoldingBall` with `return holdingBall` than you still need the `private bool holdingBall`

Comment: I put these at the top of my player class private bool holdingBall = true;

 public bool HoldingBall
 {
   get { return holdingBall; }
 }
and I still get the protection is inaccessible with player.holdingball.

Comment: You mean `player.HoldingBall`?

Comment: Yes I do. Thats what I mean.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct one .. there is a difference between `holdingBall` and `HoldingBall`! `HoldingBall` is public so it can't be that you still get that error ...

Comment: I fixed my script errors but I can't seem to add the ball to my player script in the unity editor.

Comment: is the player in the scene or are you maybe trying to do it on a prefab?

Comment: It's for the first person player in the scene. I'm trying to add the ball asset to my player script.