# Inaccessible due to its protection level?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I started learning C#, and I was trying to create a class, I saw a video, and I did the exact same thing.

But I don't understand why I'm getting this error "Student.Student(string, int, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level."

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Student Student1 =  new Student("Aya", 00001, 4.0);
            Console.WriteLine(Student1.getName());

            Student1.setGPA(3.5);
            Console.WriteLine(Student1.getGPA());

        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        private String Name;
        private int StudentId;
        private double GPA;
        private Student(String Name, int StudentId, double GPA)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.StudentId = StudentId;
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        public int getStudentId()
        {
            return this.StudentId;
        }
        public double getGPA()
        {
            return this.GPA;
        }
        public void setGPA(double GPA)
        {
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You declared the constructor as `private`. I doubt they did that in the video.

Comment: Also, a video teaching C# which uses methods `getName` and `setName` instead of a `Name` property is probably not a good choice. This looks very Java-like, not idiomatic C#. The case style isn't Java-like, but it's still not the style generally used in C#.

Comment: This is an obvious access-level problem. As a novice, I suggest you take a good look at the basics of c#, and some c# tutorials. Microsoft officially has a good tutorial, here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is private, so it cannot be accessed outside the class.
Another thing is that you can use properties, for example you can replace:

```
private String Name;
public String getName()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

with this:

```
public string Name {get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

constructor have to be public to be able to access it

https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3aW62